# DurableClient and OrchestrationTrigger cannot be used in .NET 7 Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I am now upgrading to .NET 7 Durable Function

The attributes below are not available with these

```
[DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter
[OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context
[ActivityTrigger]
```

[image]

I get an error with .NET Worker
What is the equivalent with .NET 7?

EDIT

I have got this compiling now but I get IDurableOrchestrationClient being resolved from webjobs, whats the equivalent in .NET 7?

My current packages are below

[image]

Paul

Comment: Actually, .NET 7 (In-Process) Version is not yet released for Azure Functions. Only .NET 7 Isolated Version (Out-Process) Came to Azure Functions version 4.x.

Comment: I am using Isolated Process?

Comment: Then, could you specify details like from which .NET version you're upgrading to .NET 7 Isolated version?

Comment: I am upgrading from .NET 3.1

Comment: Have you checked all those packages are compatible with .NET 7. If no, please check once in this [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/) Official Site and update them accordingly.

Comment: It looks like you have both the isolated version (Ms.Azure.Functions.Worker.Ext.DurableTask) and the in-process version (Ms.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask). You should get rid of the in-process versions.

Comment: Hello I dont know the Isolated Version equivilent of IDurableOrchestrationClient?

Answer (score 1):

This should be available now at:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/767

Answer (score 0):

Was currently attempting the same.

Out of process or isolated packages are still in RC as per https://github.com/microsoft/durabletask-dotnet and there are still features missing such as durable entities.

That said I could get to compile using .net 7, v4 of functions using below.

```
    [DurableClient] DurableClientContext durableContext,
    FunctionContext executionContext)
{
    ILogger logger = executionContext.GetLogger(nameof(StartHelloCitiesTyped));

    string instanceId = await durableContext.Client.ScheduleNewHelloCitiesTypedInstanceAsync();
```